How to backup an app's data on one phone and restore on another, without root
Old phone:  Motorola Moto G Power (2022)
New phone:  Motorola Moto G Power 5G (2024)
App:  Bloons Tower Defense 5 (Humble Bundle version)
Things I tried:

The device-transfer steps when initializing the new phone.  It appears that sideloaded apps, such as all Humble Bundle apps, do not participate (are not allowed to participate?) in Google system backups, so this data didn't carry over.
adb, several ways.  None of them actually manage to make the restore part happen.
An extended email conversation with Ninja Kiwi, the app developers.  It would be quite easy for them to add code to allow saves to/restores from a simple text file, or even a text string (the way, e.g., Cookie Clicker does), but they refused to admit it, claiming it's simply impossible.

I seem to remember the adb method working fine when I moved to the old phone from the one before that.  Is this just the enshittification of Android at work and nothing can be done?  Or am I missing some way of accomplishing this?

To my experience device transfer never transmits side-loaded APK files, it only downloads the apps from Play Store. I am not sure if app data is transferred if the app is not listed in Play Store. Most apps disallow adb backup (or any form of export) as this would allow users on unrooted devices to manipulate save game data. AFAIR since Android 12 on source device, USB transfer is also able to transfer app data of apps that disallow backup.

I'm not sure what issue there is in the alteration of single-player game data…  Also, did you mean "unable", there?

No the sentence is correct. I have read once a section on the Android developer pages that USB device-to-device sync is capable of overriding/ignoring certain adb backup restrictions if both devices are running I think Android 12 or newer. But at the moment I am not able to find this section again on the developer web page.

@Robert Hm, that's intriguing and could be most helpful…

Found it: Behavior changes: Apps targeting Android 12: D2D transfer functionality changes. However in the next section is mentioned that there is a new configuration file that allows to configure what can be transferred in a D2D backup connection. Therefore an app developer could again disable data backup/transfer between two devices.
